# WordPress static index page

Tags: php, wordpress, static

I am editing a WordPress website, and I'd like to put a static page on index like "We're under construction". But when I edit the index.php file to show this page, I can't acess **wp-login.php** anymore, because it redirects me to index.php again.

Answer (score 1):

I made a plugin just for that: [WP Show Site by IP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-show-site-by-ip/).

The advantage of using IP over login to filter your access is that sometimes you want to see your websites as an anonymous user rather than a logged in one (which could have different features/capabilities).